# Accidentally merged staging to master branch in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I need help on restoring the staging back, currently the staging is deleted because of the merge I did.

Is the "Revert" button safe to click on this situation?

[image]

Comment: If it was an accidental merge from any branch to master, your real problem is to revert the master branch which is easy. #1 is your master reverted? #2 Do you want to restore the staging branch at  commit level or you just need the files?

Comment: I just want to restore all, so restore the staging branch with all its commits and dont do anything on the master @JRichardsz as you see I merged it 2 hours ago so restore all points from before that.

Comment: initial master commits: 1,2  ........... staging (from master) commits 1,2,3,4 .......  after merge, master have these commits: 1,2,3,4  #1 Is this correct? #2 Do you need to create another branch with 1,2,3,4 (staging) commits and revert your master to : 1,2 ?